# django viewset extends mixins.UpdateModelMixin but postman updates model by patch method returns ' detail: Method PATCH not allowed'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

viewset code

```html
class UserTitleViewset(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                       mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = UserTitleMod.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserTitleSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return "ok"

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        return "ok"
```

settings.py

```html
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS'
]
```

I have tried many times but it's still not working. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Is another methods - post-get-put working ?

Comment: @a_k_v other method post and get are successful

Comment: What about PUT ?

Comment: PUT is also not allowed

Comment: Please share more info. I think problem is in your url config so update question with url

Comment: router config:
router.register(r'usertitles', UserTitleViewset, base_name="usertitles")

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\      and the request url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/usertitles/

Comment: What about urlpattern

Comment: PATCH/PUT only applies to an instance, not the list of instance. Your url should be like http://127.0.0.1:8000/usertitles/123/

Comment: @a_k_v urlpattern : url(r'^', include(router.urls)),

Comment: Did you try @Linovias solution

Comment: @Linovia I have changed the url with sn number(primary key) '1': http://127.0.0.1:8000/usertitles/1   ----------   it's still not working, it returns 'Could not get any response, There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/usertitles/1.
'